# How to find and replace something like this in vim?

Tags: regex, search, vim

Input

```
if(statement)
{
```

to Ouput

```
if ( statement ) {
```

I can find the input using

```
/if(\S\(.*\))
```

Explanation :

if( is the keyword to be searched , \S to negate whitespace , (.*) for anything in between and ) end bracket.

Need :

Trying to automate coding guideline over code written w/o coding guideline plus I am a lazy coder who wants to run autocmd for coding guidelines.

EDIT :

```
:%s/if(\S\(.*\)\S)/if ( \1 )/gc
```

Came very close but it removes the first character after the 'if(' and last char before ')'

Comment: "something like this" is too vague. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: oh boy where to start. vim has autocode formatting have a look at `:h =` which does the indentation. Depending on your coding language there are filetype plugins which do the formatting for you by setting the `formatexpr`. Then there are external linters which can be used (have a look at ale https://github.com/w0rp/ale). I would strongly suggest using the tools vim gives you and not build a regex like that.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo `=` is for indentation, not general formatting (unless you use a custom plugin that redefines it).

Comment: So, put the capturing parentheses where they should be, `if(\(\S.*\S\))`. Or `if(\(\S\(.*\S\)\?\))` to allow a single char variable inside `if` condition.

Comment: @melpomene IDK know what term to use. Sorry? Can you suggest?

Comment: @melpomene you are of course right. sorry for the confusion updated my comment. My point however still stands. The started regex approach will be painful. Thank you very much for correcting me!

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Thanks , had no idea about that. Recently started using the vim. Will look into it

Comment: Here is something for autoindent btw. "autocmd BufWritePre *.c :normal gg=G``zz "

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/if(\(\S.*\S\))/if ( \1 )/gc
```

\1 here is for replacing the first match pattern that is between ( ) so in my case it was \S.*\S

\S.*\S is for anything without any whitespace.

Comment: How will that move the `{` up, like in your example?

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing out. Will google, find , implement and get back :D

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `:substitute` here; you already have the regular expression, you can use that with [`:global`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) to find all lines and then [`:join`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Ajoin) them with the next one:

```
:global /if(\S\(.*\))/join
```

If you prefer `:substitute`, you can do that as well, by matching the newline (`\n`), any indent, and the opening curly. I use `\zs` here to limit the match; this saves me from using *capturing groups*:

```
:%substitute/if(\S\(.*\)\zs\n\s*{/ {/
```

#### Attention! Caveats

You say your intention is automation of coding guidelines. While Vim commands such as the above are fine for occasional tactical edits, I would not base an automated (presumably not thoroughly checked by a human) tool on regular expressions, as they can only *approximate* the syntax of most programming languages. It's fine for Vim's syntax highlighting, where you can live with the occasional misrepresentation. It's something different to directly work on the source code itself. For that, there are better tools that directly implement the language's syntax rules (usually not via regular expressions, but a full-blown and tested parser). You don't mention the language, but a quick search for *«language» linter* or *«language» code style check* should give you something to start.

Comment: Ok. The attention does make sense but it was fun to learn. Won't use it to edit source code. Point taken. No idea regarding linter or code style checker. I am gonna use C language specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this vim automation expression:

```
:%s/\vif\((.*)\)/if ( \1 )/gc
```